# How to use Xcode SceneKit Editor's 'bake' functionality programmatically?

Tags: xcode, 3d, textures, scenekit, collada

We have about 17,000 3D models (folders including DAE files + textures) and we're trying to use the bake functionality on all of them so we can use these 3D files in production (models look better with baked textures).

[image: Bake functionality]

Is there any way we can automate this process without importing every model in Xcode and doing it manually? E.g. a command line tool?

[Apple's Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio) framework has classes with methods like **[generateAmbientOcclusionVertexColorsWithRaysPerSample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmesh/1390975-generateambientocclusionvertexco?language=objc)** which I thought might be helpful but I just can't figure out how to use this framework correctly to save these options as an SCNScene to a file. It makes it even harder since I don't have that much experience with 3D files so everything looks like gibberish to me.